# Waterproofing a GPS antena

Tags: rf, antenna

I need to use this [GPS antenna](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/GPS/embeddedsma.pdf) on a model boat. As a result of placement, it will be submerged periodically (though I don't expect it to work while submerged), and damp often. What can I encase it in that won't degrade its performance while dry? I've considered simple two-part epoxy (the translucent kind), but worry about signal attenuation.

Comment: Will it be saltwater or fresh water?  Many off-the-shelf active antennas (I like the ANT-GPS-SH) will be fine with periodic submersion in fresh water.  Salt is much harder to deal with both for the antenna and for the equipment you're going to attach to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are dozens of waterproof GPS antennas that have elements such as you indicate inside.  Most have a LNA amplifier stage as well to compensate for the cable losses. A decade ago they were under US$ 5.00 each in 50 quantities.

When casing your antenna I would keep a few mm of space between the antenna and adjacent dielectric parts to prevent detuning.  I would also keep all metal away from above and adjacent to the antenna for at least 10mm.  The thickness of the radome on these small commercial ceramic patch antennas is typically 0.8 to 1.2mm and may even be required to get the correct frequency when installed.

I would go with a already encased unit unless there is a compelling reason to embed it into a covert location.  If hiding it I would put a small dome to give it an air space and then cover it with fibreglass and polyester resin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any enclosures but metal which blocks RF signal.

For safety, use [IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code) rated enclosures which is rated least 7 for waterproof(liquid ingression).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encase something with a wire against submersion you need "soft contact" around the wire. Something springy.

When choosing a default IP67+ box you should make sure there's a nice place to have the wire go out past a piece of rubber pushing all around the wire.

When choosing an encasing compound, you should try to avoid using only hard and shrinking materials such as epoxy and polyester.

If the antenna has no electrical bits reachable to you, you could try a layer of two-part silicone rubber, or some similar rubber-like compound.

If it isn't a huge block you're making, the attenuation should be minimal. Best might be to make it a 3mm to 5mm layer of tough rubber or such.

I have not actually researched my two-part silicone as well as epoxy and polyester for chemical make-up, so I cannot say how much the chemicals will interfere with metals or electronics, as such my advise to use it only for an already non-IP67+ plastic box. 
If it hasn't got an outer box, first find out what the chemicals might do.